# My ESTA has been refused

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, applications, criminal-records

I’m planning on going to New York July 2020, I just applied for my ESTA and have been refused due to me having GBH ([Grievous Bodily Harm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grievous_bodily_harm)) on my record what can I do now to try and get to the USA?

Comment: Apply for a visa, that's the potential solution because sneaking in as an undocumented immigrant is not an option.

Comment: If "gbh" is assault causing grievous bodily harm, as MichaelHampton sugggest, then that is a [crime involving moral turpitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_turpitude), and a conviction forever disqualifies you from using the Visa Waiver Program. You'll need to apply for a visa instead.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to apply for a B-visa. Good job you applied for the ESTA long before you intended to travel.